# How does dplyr::do work with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

The `dplyr::do` does not seem to work for `data.table`:

```
# this works
data.frame(1) %>% 
  do(data.frame(1))
##   X1
## 1  1
# same for a data.table does not work
data.table(1) %>% 
  do(data.frame(1))
## Error in do_.data.table(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
##  argument ".f" is missing, with no default
```

Some investigation lead to the functions `do` and `do_.data.table`:

```
do
## function (.data, ...) 
## {
## do_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
## }
## <environment: namespace:dplyr>
dplyr:::do_.data.table
## function (.data, .f, ...) 
## {
## list(.f(as.data.frame(.data), ...))
## }
## <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

How does this work? Clearly the arguments of `do_.data.table` are not compatible with what it gets from `do`. And the result of `do_.data.table` is a list instead of a `data.frame`. How do I use `do` or `do_` with `data.table` input?

I know that I can use `df %>% data.frame %>% do(...)`, but I was hoping for a direct solution.

Comment: +1 From what you pasted it seems that `.f` is the function that is called on the original data and the arguments you provide (e.g. it can be `.f = data.frame` or `cbind`), so I would say the *how* is answered in your post, the question is rather *why* it returns a list... No idea about that! You can follow it by ``... %>% `[[`(1)`` to get the data frame returned inside the list, but you probably know that already:)

Comment: Looks like a bug - can you please supply a minimal reprex on dplyr's github page?

Comment: @hadley: opened [issue #1081](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1081)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `do_` will do `.f` with your arguments and return it in a list.

```
data.table(1) %>%  
  do_(data.frame(2), data.frame(3), .f = function(x1, x2, x3) cbind(x1, x2, x3))

# [[1]]
#   V1 X2 X3
# 1  1  2  3
```

Don't know about `do` though.

Comment: You can simply use `.f = cbind` to avoid specifying the number of arguments

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that it doesn't know what function to apply because you aren't providing anything for `.f` that it can work with. If you put in a function, it works:

```
data.table(1) %>% 
  do(function(x) data.frame(x))
```

returns

```
[[1]]
  V1
1  1
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my installation (3.1.2, data.table_1.9.4 dplyr_0.4.1)

Comment: I was using dplyr 0.3.0.2 and after updating to the current version I get an error. Interesting that it worked and now doesn't.